# Access Data Sent to NodeJS Server via Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

How do I access the data sent to a Nodejs Server via Ajax POST?

```
    //Client
$.ajax( {
    url: '/getExp',
    data: 'Idk Whats Rc',
    type: 'POST',
});

//Server
app.post('/getExp', function(req, res){
    var data = req.???; //I want data to be equal to 'Idk Whats Rc'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you extract POST data in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Express 4.x:**

Express 4 no longer contains Connect as a dependency, which means you will need to install the body parsing module separately.

The parser middleware can be found at its own GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). It can be installed like so:

```
npm install body-parser
```

For form data, this is how the middleware would be used:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

---

**For Express 3.x and before:**

You need to use the `bodyParser()` middleware in Express which parses the raw body of your HTTP request. The middleware then populates `req.body`.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/path', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

You might want to pass an object instead of a string to your POST request because what you currently have will come out like this:

```
{ 'Idk Whats Rc': '' }
```

Using code somewhat like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/getExp',
  data: { str: 'Idk Whats Rc' },
  type: 'POST',
});
```

Will get you this:

```
{ str: 'Idk Whats Rc' }
```