# Get post data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post

I believe the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js) question is out of date because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808930/access-data-sent-to-nodejs-server-via-ajax-post) answer.

I've read solutions about a npm packaged called body-parser, but I don't want to use it if I can find another way. I just simply want to parse POST data in node.

I have an ajax function like this:

```
$.ajax {
    url: '/foo',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
}
```

something like:

```
app.post('/foo', function(req, res) {
    var postFoo = req.foo; // How do I do this? 
});
```

Comment: You told you don't want to use body-parser but accepted an answer that tells to use it??

Comment: I should read more carefully, because my answer technically is wrong! Why do you not want to use body-parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `body-parser` middleware:

```
$ npm install body-parser --save
```

Then:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/foo', function (req, res) {
  // req.body is a plain object
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
req.body.foo
```

like this:

```
app.post('/foo', function(req, res) {
    var postFoo = req.body.foo;
});
```

The request can hold a lot of information such as the requesting user, headers, and the body of the request. The body holds the actual data that was passed along by the ajax-request.